# How to pass multiple parameters into an Azure RM Template Custom Script Extension

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to pass multiple parameters to a Custom Script Extension using an ARM template, here is a snippet of the ARM template that currently works without issue:

```
{
            "name": "Microsoft.CustomScriptExtension-20210604105657",
            "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                    "uri": "https://catalogartifact.azureedge.net/publicartifactsmigration/Microsoft.CustomScriptExtension-arm.2.0.56/Artifacts/MainTemplate.json"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "vmName": {
                        "value": "real-vm-name"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "value": "uksouth"
                    },
                    "fileUris": {
                        "value": "https://realwebsite/script.ps1"
                    },
                    "arguments": {
                        "value": "[parameters('param1')]"
                    }
                }
            },
```

But whenever I add another parameter to the arguments section, the template validation fails. This is what I have tried to do:

```
                        "arguments": {
                            "value": "[parameters('param1')], [parameters('param2')]"
                        }
```

Please can somebody help?

Comment: Can you provide the actual error for when it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to concat or format the parameters depending on what parameters you're using like this:

```
 "value": "[concat(parameters('param1'), parameters('param2'))]"
```

```
 "value": "[format(parameters('param1'), parameters('param2'))]"
```

The Azure doc I referred to:

[ARM Deployment Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-deployment-script#add-the-deployment-script)

[Concat function for ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-deployment-script#add-the-deployment-script)

[Format function for ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-deployment-script#add-the-deployment-script)

Comment: Thank you Ked, this was exactly the thing I needed. Concat worked perfectly, thank you again!